# Print Class Objects for Selected Treeview items

Tags: python, treeview, pyside

How can I retrieve the class objects of the selected treeview items? Is there a way i can instance the actual class object 'Asset' onto each tree item so it's easier for me to later retrieve or edit it?

If you look at my code below, When the user hits the 'Apply' button I would like it to print all the selected 'Asset' class objects in the treeview, how can i do this?

could someone show me how to sublcass QStandardItem and get it working for my tool?

Here is my class object.

```
class Asset(object):
    def __init__(self, name="", nickname=""):
        self.name = name
        self.nickname = nickname
        self.age = random.randint(1, 10)
        self.number = random.randint(1, 10)
        self.size = random.uniform(0.0, 100.0)
```

[image]

```
from __future__ import print_function
# Modules
import sys
import random
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Asset(object):
    def __init__(self, name="", nickname=""):
        self.name = name
        self.nickname = nickname
        self.age = random.randint(1, 10)
        self.number = random.randint(1, 10)
        self.size = random.uniform(0.0, 100.0)

class ToolTest(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ToolTest, self).__init__()

        # ui
        self.setWindowTitle(self.tr("Tool"))
        self.setMinimumWidth(150)
        self.setMinimumHeight(150)

        # treeview
        self.uiAssetViewer = QtGui.QTreeView()
        self.uiAssetViewer.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.uiAssetViewer.setModel(createAssetsModel(self))
        self.uiAssetViewer.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.uiAssetViewer.sortByColumn(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.uiAssetViewer.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.uiAssetViewer.header().setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.uiAssetViewer.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.uiAssetViewer.header().setStretchLastSection(False)

        self.uiRunRenamer = QtGui.QPushButton("Apply")

        # layout: controls
        gdl = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        gdl.setContentsMargins(10, 5, 10, 5)
        gdl.addWidget(self.uiAssetViewer, 0, 0)
        gdl.addWidget(self.uiRunRenamer, 1, 0)

        # main layout
        main_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        main_widget.setLayout(gdl)
        self.setCentralWidget(main_widget)

        # actions
        self.uiRunRenamer.clicked.connect(self.printData)

    def printData(self):
        print ("Printing Selected Data...")



def addAsset(model, asset):
    model.insertRow(0)
    model.setData(model.index(0, 0), asset.name)
    model.setData(model.index(0, 1), asset.nickname)

    model.setData(model.index(0, 1),
                  QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(50, 80, 190, 255)),
                  QtCore.Qt.ForegroundRole)

def createAssetsModel(parent):
    columns = ["Name","New Name"]

    model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(parent)
    model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(columns)

    addAsset(model, Asset("Josh", "J-Dog"))
    addAsset(model, Asset("Kevin", "Kev"))
    addAsset(model, Asset("Michael", "Mike"))
    addAsset(model, Asset("Curt", "Urbanis"))
    addAsset(model, Asset("Michelle", "El"))

    return model


# Main
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ToolTest()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Make `Asset` a subclass of `QStandardItem`.

Comment: @ekhumoro could you demonstrate how i would do that? I'm not super familiar with doing stuff like that. this would be a good simple example